# Mirror effect in documents

Tags: formatting, text-manipulation

The following [example](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/6553-sample.pdf) (links to pdf) in the [TeX Showcase](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/) has no provided source. The book [Fearless Symmetry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691124922) by Ash and Gross seems to use a similar style. Where can I find hints for typesetting publication standard articles/books as above in TeX. I looked around a bit but couldnt find much from else from keyword searches.

Particularly, I am looking at the chapter headings, title page design, and the mirror effect. Sorry for the title, as I dont really know what its called.

Comment: I'm curious, did you manage to build a macro that does below-the-line mirroring of arbitrary text with alpha blending as in the Fearless Symmetry book? Not that I need it right now but if you already built it, I'd be curious to see the code.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This would be a general solution to your question of mirroring, as supplied by the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). It provides `\reflectbox{<stuff>}` which reflects `<stuff>` horizontally. It is equivalent to `\scalebox{-1}[1]{<stuff>}` where the syntax is `\scalebox{<h-scale>}[<v-scale>]{<stuff>}` and `h-scale`/`v-scale` are scaling factors. For vertical reflection, one can use `\scalebox{1}[-1]{<stuff>}`, and add a vertical raise of `\depth` (using `\raisebox`). Otherwise, the reflection is performed from the baseline. Here are a couple of examples to showcase the symmetries of reflection with a variety of macros from `graphicx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\textbf{Horizontal reflection}: \par
Here is some text that is \reflectbox{reflected} horizontally. \par
Here is some text that is \scalebox{-1}[1]{also reflected} horizontally. \par \bigskip
\textbf{Vertical reflection}: \par
Here is some text \raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{reflected}} vertically. \par \bigskip
\textbf{Horizontal + vertical reflection}: \par
Here is some text that is \raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{-1}[-1]{reflected}} both horizontally and vertically. \par
Here is some text that is \raisebox{\depth}{\rotatebox{180}{also reflected}} both horizontally and vertically.
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to reflect horizontally the whole document?

Comment: @Sigur: Yes, using [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi). For example, consider: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,atbegshi,showframe}
\AtBeginShipout{\setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox=\hbox{\hspace*{\dimexpr1in-\marginparsep}\reflectbox{\box\AtBeginShipoutBox}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}`

Answer (score 7):

With ConTeXt you can use `\mirror`. Here an example:

```
\starttext
    Some text\par
    \mirror{Some Text}\par
    \input knuth\par
    \mirror{\vbox{\input knuth\par}}
\stoptext
```

Some info [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Graphical_text_manipulation).

Answer (score 7):

A simple mirror effect can be created using `\reflectbox{<text>}` (short for `\scalebox{-1}[1]{<text>}`) from the `graphicx` package. The `adjustbox` package has the same effects using the `reflect` key: `\adjustbox{reflect}{<text>}`, which makes sense if you have more effects you want to apply.

You can mirror a text downwards using `\scalebox{1}[-1]{<text>}`.

More complex effects require a package like TikZ. See the [`pgfmanual`](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) which has this effect on it own start page, inclusive code.