# Reflect line of text about y axis

Tags: formatting

Is there an easy way (i.e. without using TikZ, say) to write a line of text backwards? By which I roughly mean, the entire text is reflected about the y axis.

I only need it for a Beamer heading, not anything more general like a hyphenated paragraph.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82759/) may be related.

Comment: Use `\reflectbox{<your text here>}` ([`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) already inludes [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) that provides this functionality). Could you elaborate on what you mean by "heading"?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Mirror effect in documents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34713/5764)

Comment: Oh, right. That was easy :) And "heading" was a bit unclear - I just mean any text that fits onto a single line. I.e. I'm not worried about justification or hyphenation of reflected text.

Comment: @Werner I'm inclined to say this is a duplicate (I searched quite hard, but didn't think of looking for "mirror".) I've edited the names of both questions accordingly.

Comment: Let's close this as a duplicate rather. That way, when people find this question, they will have a link to the other question. That's the advantage of having a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, good point. So both "mirror" and "reflect" should eventually lead to the answer. Thanks!